# This sql select must be optimized...how?

Tags: mysql

Here is my query

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    SM.sales_date,
    (SELECT 
            SUM(gross_sale)
        FROM
            sales_main AS INTERNAL
        WHERE
            INTERNAL.sales_date = SM.sales_date AND INTERNAL.vehicle_name=SM.vehicle_name) AS TGROSS,
    (SELECT 
            SUM(net_sale)
        FROM
            sales_main AS INTERNAL
        WHERE
            INTERNAL.sales_date = SM.sales_date AND INTERNAL.vehicle_name=SM.vehicle_name) AS TNET,
    (SELECT 
            SUM(cash)
        FROM
            sales_main AS INTERNAL
        WHERE
            INTERNAL.sales_date = SM.sales_date AND INTERNAL.vehicle_name=SM.vehicle_name) AS TCASH,
    (SELECT 
            SUM(cheque)
        FROM
            sales_main AS INTERNAL
        WHERE
            INTERNAL.sales_date = SM.sales_date AND INTERNAL.vehicle_name=SM.vehicle_name) AS TCHEQUE,
    (SELECT 
            SUM(credit)
        FROM
            sales_main AS INTERNAL
        WHERE
            INTERNAL.sales_date = SM.sales_date AND INTERNAL.vehicle_name=SM.vehicle_name) AS TCREDIT,
    (SELECT 
            SUM((SELECT 
                        amount
                    FROM
                        sales_main_deduction AS INTERNAL
                    WHERE
                        INTERNAL.instance = '4%' AND INTERNAL.idsales_main = SMinternal.idsales_main))
        FROM
            sales_main AS SMinternal
        WHERE
            SMinternal.sales_date = SM.sales_date AND SMinternal.vehicle_name=SM.vehicle_name) AS '4%'
            ,
    (SELECT 
            SUM((SELECT 
                        amount
                    FROM
                        sales_main_deduction AS INTERNAL
                    WHERE
                        INTERNAL.instance = '6%' AND INTERNAL.idsales_main = SMinternal.idsales_main))
        FROM
            sales_main AS SMinternal
        WHERE
            SMinternal.sales_date = SM.sales_date AND SMinternal.vehicle_name=SM.vehicle_name) AS '6%',
    (SELECT 
            SUM((SELECT 
                        amount
                    FROM
                        sales_main_deduction AS INTERNAL
                    WHERE
                        INTERNAL.instance = '10%' AND INTERNAL.idsales_main = SMinternal.idsales_main))
        FROM
            sales_main AS SMinternal
        WHERE
            SMinternal.sales_date = SM.sales_date AND SMinternal.vehicle_name=SM.vehicle_name) AS '10%',
    (SELECT 
            SUM((SELECT 
                        amount
                    FROM
                        sales_main_deduction AS INTERNAL
                    WHERE
                        INTERNAL.instance = 'M/R' AND INTERNAL.idsales_main = SMinternal.idsales_main))
        FROM
            sales_main AS SMinternal
        WHERE
            SMinternal.sales_date = SM.sales_date AND SMinternal.vehicle_name=SM.vehicle_name) AS 'M/R',
    (SELECT 
            SUM((SELECT 
                        amount
                    FROM
                        sales_main_deduction AS INTERNAL
                    WHERE
                        INTERNAL.instance = 'S/R' AND INTERNAL.idsales_main = SMinternal.idsales_main))
        FROM
            sales_main AS SMinternal
        WHERE
            SMinternal.sales_date = SM.sales_date AND SMinternal.vehicle_name=SM.vehicle_name) AS 'S/R'
FROM
    sales_main AS SM
WHERE
    (SM.sales_date >= '2013-06-01' AND SM.sales_date <= '2013-06-05') AND SM.vehicle_name='Lorry1'
```

and this is the result..

```
2013-06-01  59582.03  58336.59  32096.96  11141.02  15098.59  1245.44                
2013-06-03  132334.45  126461.84  33138.93  11046.63  82276.28  1774.46 557.02  3541.13  2013-06-04  72184.69  71882.93  27840.74  12410.16  31632.03   152.16    149.6     
2013-06-05  93478.20  86721.32  34461.47  24971.24  27288.6  934.48  3553.32  2269.08
```

But this if this queryextends to 31 days of month it takes 10 mins to return a results from 2000 rows table ....please help..

Comment: Use MySQL explain to see why your query is slow. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why on earth all those inner queries?

Transform all (I just give example)

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    SM.sales_date,
    (SELECT 
            SUM(gross_sale)
        FROM
            sales_main AS INTERNAL
        WHERE
            INTERNAL.sales_date = SM.sales_date AND INTERNAL.vehicle_name=SM.vehicle_name) AS TGROSS,
    (SELECT 
            SUM(net_sale)
        FROM
            sales_main AS INTERNAL
        WHERE
            INTERNAL.sales_date = SM.sales_date AND INTERNAL.vehicle_name=SM.vehicle_name) AS TNET,
```

To:

```
SELECT 
       sales_date,
       SUM(gross_sale) AS TGROSS,
       SUM(net_sale) AS TNET
FROM
            sales_main
        WHERE
            sales_date BETWEEN X AND Y 
         AND 
             vehicle_name=vehicle_name
GROUP BY YEAR(sales_date), MONTH(sales_date), DAY(sales_date)
```

Once you have that working, we can further optimize it.

The `GROUP BY` can also be just `GROUP BY sales_date` if sales_date is of `DATE` type, and `DATE(sales_date)` if it is `DATETIME` type.
I used that group by for the `WITH ROLLUP` summary of groups I am used to do in my reporting service...

Comment: I did it bro,,then it retunrs only one row !

Comment: Aha i missed the GRUOP BY ...thanks .it worked

Comment: `GROUP BY YEAR(sales_date),MONTH(sales_date),DAY(sales_date)`? Why not just `GROUP BY sales_date`?

Comment: @ypercube well...in my system I do also WITH ROLEUP...but your comment is defenitly correct if no such thing is needed

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with conditional aggregation, all in one query:

```
SELECT SM.sales_date,
       sum(sm.gross_sale) as gross_sale,
       sum(sm.net_sale) as net_sale,
       sum(case when sm.instance = 'M/R'  then amount end) as MR,
       sum(case when sm.instance = 'S/R'  then amount end) as SR
from sales_main sm
WHERE (SM.sales_date >= '2013-06-01' AND SM.sales_date <= '2013-06-05') AND
      SM.vehicle_name='Lorry1'
group by sm.sales_date
order by 1;
```

I have assumed that the `sales_date` is stored as a `date` with no time on it.